# Scrolling with two fingers with a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have an app where my main view accepts both `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved`, and therefore takes in single finger touches, and drags.  I want to implement a `UIScrollView`, and I have it working, but it overrides the drags, and therefore my contentView never receives them.   I'd like to implement a `UIScrollview`, where a two finger drag indicates a scroll, and a one finger drag event gets passed to my content view, so it performs normally.   Do I need create my own subclass of `UIScrollView`?

Here's my code from my `appDelegate` where I implement the `UIScrollView`.

```
@implementation MusicGridAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;
@synthesize scrollView;


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    // Override point for customization after app launch    
    //[application setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    //[window addSubview:viewController.view];

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(720, 480);
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    [scrollView addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [viewController release];
    [scrollView release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to subclass UIScrollView (of course!). Then you need to:

- make single-finger events to go to your content view (easy), and
- make two-finger events scroll the scroll view (may be easy, may be hard, may be impossible).

Patrick's suggestion is generally fine: let your UIScrollView subclass know about your content view, then in touch event handlers check the number of fingers and forward the event accordingly. Just be sure that (1) the events you send to content view don't bubble back to UIScrollView through the responder chain (i.e. make sure to handle them all), (2) respect the usual flow of touch events (i.e. touchesBegan, than some number of {touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded}, finished with touchesEnded or touchesCancelled), especially when dealing with UIScrollView. #2 can be tricky.

If you decide the event is for UIScrollView, another trick is to make UIScrollView believe your two-finger gesture is actually a one-finger gesture (because UIScrollView cannot be scrolled with two fingers). Try passing only the data for one finger to super (by filtering the `(NSSet *)touches` argument — note that it only contains the changed touches — and ignoring events for the wrong finger altogether).

If that does not work, you are in trouble. Theoretically you can try to create artificial touches to feed to UIScrollView by creating a class that looks similar to UITouch. Underlying C code does not check types, so maybe casting (YourTouch *) into (UITouch *) will work, and you will be able to trick UIScrollView into handling the touches that did not really happen.

You probably want to read [my article on advanced UIScrollView tricks](http://github.com/andreyvit/ScrollingMadness/tree/master) (and see some totally unrelated UIScrollView sample code there).

Of course, if you can't get it to work, there's always an option of either controlling UIScrollView's movement manually, or use an entirely custom-written scroll view. There's TTScrollView class in [Three20 library](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/tree/master); it does not feel good to the user, but does feel good to programmer.

Comment: Andrey,
    Thanks for your explanation.  I actually got it working by passing a subset of the touches to super... I created an NSSet of just one touch event, and passed that.  However, should I be passing the same UIEvent in that call?  Or do I need modify something in the event before passing it?  I'm getting some unexpected behavior with scrolling back, and I think it's because of the UIevent I'm passing to super is the original event and the NSSet of touches is modified to have only one touch.

Comment: Craid, I don't believe you can modify UIEvent, so if you are right about the cause, you are in trouble. :)

Answer (score 66):

In SDK 3.2 the touch handling for UIScrollView is handled using Gesture Recognizers.

If you want to do two-finger panning instead of the default one-finger panning, you can use the following code:

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer in scrollView.gestureRecognizers) {     
    if ([gestureRecognizer  isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGR = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer;
        panGR.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;               
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but the scrollview is, for some reason, detecting any multi-touches as separate single touches (i.e: a two finger swipe is detected as two single fingers), so the gesture is never called. Any ideas?

Comment: I got this solution to work by also setting: panGR.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2; It seems that it's set to one. This by far is the easiest way to get double finger scrolling working.

Comment: This worked great for me. Much cleaner than subclassing UIScrollView to make this simple change.

Comment: Fantastic stuff - very quick and easy solution to this problem.

Comment: I tried all of this and all I get is: Ignoring call to [UIPanGestureRecognizer setTranslation:inView:] since gesture recognizer is not active, multitouch is enabled

Comment: absolutely awesome answer...!

Answer (score 48):

For iOS 5+, setting this property has the same effect as the answer by Mike Laurence:

```
self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;
```

One finger dragging is ignored by panGestureRecognizer and so the one finger drag event gets passed to the content view.

Comment: Agreed, this fixed my problem immediately. Thanks Guto!

Comment: Indeed. Who uses iOS 4 nowadays?

Answer (score 14):

In iOS 3.2+ you can now achieve two-finger scrolling quite easily. Just add a pan gesture recognizer to the scroll view and set its maximumNumberOfTouches to 1. It will claim all single-finger scrolls, but allow 2+ finger scrolls to pass up the chain to the scroll view's built-in pan gesture recognizer (and thus allow normal scrolling behavior).

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(recognizePan:)];
panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
[panGestureRecognizer release];
```

Comment: Works nicely. Although while the view is still scrolling from a previous two-finger gesture, placing one finger on the screen keeps dragging the view. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: @sharvey, you could minimize this by removing bouncing. I'm still  looking for other ways...

Comment: @Yar Did you ever find another way to prevent this?

Comment: This seems to work the best for me of all the answers on this page.

Answer (score 8):

This answers are a mess since you can only find the correct answer by reading all the other answers and the comments (closest answer got the question backwards). The accepted answer is too vague to be useful, and suggests a different method.

Synthesizing, this works

```
    // makes it so that only two finger scrolls go
    for (id gestureRecognizer in self.gestureRecognizers) {     
        if ([gestureRecognizer  isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]])
        {
            UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGR = gestureRecognizer;
            panGR.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;              
            panGR.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2;
        }
    }
```

This requires two fingers for a scroll. I've done this in a subclass, but if not, just replace `self.gestureRecognizers` with `myScrollView.gestureRecognizers` and you're good to go.

The only thing that I added is using `id` to avoid an ugly cast :)

**This works but can get quite messy if you want your UIScrollView to do zoom too... the gestures don't work correctly, since pinch-to-zoom and scroll fight it out. I'll update this if I find a suitable answer.**

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it just makes the UIScrollView not scroll at all.

Comment: @RichardSmith go back to a simplest-possible example and test it. It definitely works for two-finger scroll.

Answer (score 2):

we managed to implement similar functionality in our iPhone drawing app by subclassing UIScrollView and filtering events depending on number of touches in simple and rude way:

```
//OCRScroller.h
@interface OCRUIScrollView: UIScrollView
{
    double pass2scroller;
}
@end

//OCRScroller.mm
@implementation OCRUIScrollView
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect {
    pass2scroller = 0;
    UIScrollView* newv = [super initWithFrame:aRect];
    return newv;
}
- (void)setupPassOnEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    int touch_cnt = [[event allTouches] count];
    if(touch_cnt<=1){
        pass2scroller = 0;
    }else{
        double timems = double(CACurrentMediaTime()*1000);
        pass2scroller = timems+200;
    }
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self setupPassOnEvent:event];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self setupPassOnEvent:event];
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];   
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    pass2scroller = 0;
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}


- (BOOL)touchesShouldBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inContentView:(UIView *)view
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view
{
    double timems = double(CACurrentMediaTime()*1000);
    if (pass2scroller == 0 || timems> pass2scroller){
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
@end
```

ScrollView setuped as follows:

```
scroll_view = [[OCRUIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
scroll_view.contentSize = img_size;
scroll_view.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,0);
scroll_view.canCancelContentTouches = YES;
scroll_view.delaysContentTouches = NO;
scroll_view.scrollEnabled = YES;
scroll_view.bounces = NO;
scroll_view.bouncesZoom = YES;
scroll_view.maximumZoomScale = 10.0f;
scroll_view.minimumZoomScale = 0.1f;
scroll_view.delegate = self;
self.view = scroll_view;
```

---

simple tap does nothing (you can handle it in the way you need), tap with two fingers scrolls/zooms view as expected. no GestureRecognizer is used, so works from iOS 3.1

Answer (score 2):

I've got a further improvement to the code above. The problem was, that even after we set `setCanCancelContentTouches:NO`  We have the problem, that a zoom gesture will interrupt with the content. It won't cancel the content touch but allow zooming in the meantime. TO prevent this i lock the zooming by setting the minimumZoomScale and maximumZoomScale to the same values everytime, the timer fires.

A quite strange behavior is that when a one finger event gets canceled by a two finger gesture within the allowed time period, the timer will be delayed. It gets fired after the touchCanceled Event gets called. So we have the problem,  that we try to lock the zooming although the event is already canceled and therefore disable zooming for the next event.
To handle this behavior the timer callback method checks against if touchesCanceled was called before. 

    `@implementation JWTwoFingerScrollView`

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Event Passing


- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        for (UIGestureRecognizer* r in self.gestureRecognizers) {
            if ([r isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
                [((UIPanGestureRecognizer*)r) setMaximumNumberOfTouches:2];
                [((UIPanGestureRecognizer*)r) setMinimumNumberOfTouches:2];
                zoomScale[0] = -1.0;
                zoomScale[1] = -1.0;
            }
            timerWasDelayed = NO;
        }
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)lockZoomScale {    
    zoomScale[0] = self.minimumZoomScale;
    zoomScale[1] = self.maximumZoomScale;
    [self setMinimumZoomScale:self.zoomScale];
    [self setMaximumZoomScale:self.zoomScale];
        NSLog(@"locked %.2f %.2f",self.minimumZoomScale,self.maximumZoomScale);
}
-(void)unlockZoomScale {
    if (zoomScale[0] != -1 && zoomScale[1] != -1) {
        [self setMinimumZoomScale:zoomScale[0]];
        [self setMaximumZoomScale:zoomScale[1]];
        zoomScale[0] = -1.0;
        zoomScale[1] = -1.0;
        NSLog(@"unlocked %.2f %.2f",self.minimumZoomScale,self.maximumZoomScale);
    }
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"began %i",[event allTouches].count);
    [self setCanCancelContentTouches:YES];
     if ([event allTouches].count == 1){
         touchesBeganTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(firstTouchTimerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
         [touchesBeganTimer retain];
         [touchFilter touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
     }
 }

//if one finger touch gets canceled by two finger touch, this timer gets delayed
// so we can! use this method to disable zooming, because it doesnt get called when two finger touch events are wanted; otherwise we would disable zooming while zooming
-(void)firstTouchTimerFired:(NSTimer*)timer {
    NSLog(@"fired");
    [self setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
    //if already locked: unlock
    //this happens because two finger gesture delays timer until touch event finishes.. then we dont want to lock!
    if (timerWasDelayed) {
        [self unlockZoomScale];
    }
    else {
        [self lockZoomScale];
    }
    timerWasDelayed = NO;
 }

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
//    NSLog(@"moved %i",[event allTouches].count);
    [touchFilter touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

 - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"ended %i",[event allTouches].count);
    [touchFilter touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    [self unlockZoomScale];
 }

 //[self setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
 -(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"canceled %i",[event allTouches].count);
    [touchFilter touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    [self unlockZoomScale];
     timerWasDelayed = YES;
 }

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Bad news: iPhone SDK 3.0 and up, don't pass touches to `-touchesBegan:` and -`touchesEnded:` **`UIScrollview`**subclass methods anymore. You can use the `touchesShouldBegin` and `touchesShouldCancelInContentView` methods that is not the same.

If you really want to get this touches, have one *hack* that allow this.

In your subclass of `UIScrollView` override the `hitTest` method like this:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

  UIView *result = nil;
  for (UIView *child in self.subviews)
    if ([child pointInside:point withEvent:event])
      if ((result = [child hitTest:point withEvent:event]) != nil)
        break;

  return result;
}
```

This will pass to you subclass this touches, however you can't cancel the touches to `UIScrollView` super class.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is have my view controller set up the scroll view:

```
[scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
[scrollView setDelaysContentTouches:NO];
```

And in my child view I have a timer because two-finger touches usually start out as one finger followed quickly by two fingers.:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // Hand tool or two or more touches means a pan or zoom gesture.
    if ((selectedTool == kHandToolIndex) || (event.allTouches.count > 1)) {
        [[self parentScrollView] setCanCancelContentTouches:YES];
        [firstTouchTimer invalidate];
        firstTouchTimer = nil;
        return;
    }

    // Use a timer to delay first touch because two-finger touches usually start with one touch followed by a second touch.
    [[self parentScrollView] setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
    anchorPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    firstTouchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kFirstTouchTimeInterval target:self selector:@selector(firstTouchTimerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    firstTouchTimeStamp = event.timestamp;
}
```

If a second touchesBegan: event comes in with more than one finger, the scroll view is allowed to cancel touches. So if the user pans using two fingers, this view would get a `touchesCanceled:` message.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the best resource for this question on the internet.  Another close solution [can be found here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/6686-uiscrollview-wont-respond-touch-event-scrolls-pans-but-tochesshouldbegin-ne.html).

I have solved this issue in a very satisfactory manner in a different way, essentially by supplanting my own gesture recognizer into the equation.  I strongly recommend that anyone who is trying to achieve the effect requested by the original poster consider this alternative over aggressive subclassing of `UIScrollView`.

The following process will provide:

- A `UIScrollView` containing your custom view
- Zoom and Pan with two fingers (via `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`)
- Your view's event processing for all other touches

First, let's assume you have a view controller and its view.  In IB, make the view a subview of a scrollView and adjust the resize rules of your view so that it does not resize.  In the attributes of the scrollview, turn on anything that says "bounce" and turn *off* "`delaysContentTouches`".  Also you must set the zoom min and max to other than the default of 1.0 for, as Apple's docs say, this is required for zooming to work.

Create a custom subclass of `UIScrollView`, and make this scrollview that custom subclass.  Add an outlet to your view controller for the scrollview and connect them up.  You're now totally configured.

You will need to add the following code to the `UIScrollView` subclass so that it transparently passes touch events (I suspect this could be done more elegantly, perhaps even bypassing the subclass altogether):

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Event Passing

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.nextResponder touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.nextResponder touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view {
    return NO;
}
```

Add this code to your view controller:

```
- (void)setupGestures {
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinchGesture:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
    [pinchGesture release];
}

- (IBAction)handlePinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender {
if ( sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ) {
    //Hold values
    previousLocation = [sender locationInView:self.view];
    previousOffset = self.scrollView.contentOffset;
    previousScale = self.scrollView.zoomScale;
} else if ( sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged ) {
    //Zoom
    [self.scrollView setZoomScale:previousScale*sender.scale animated:NO];

    //Move
    location = [sender locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(previousOffset.x+(previousLocation.x-location.x), previousOffset.y+(previousLocation.y-location.y));
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:offset animated:NO];  
} else {
    if ( previousScale*sender.scale < 1.15 && previousScale*sender.scale > .85 )
        [self.scrollView setZoomScale:1.0 animated:YES];
}
```

}

Please note that in this method there are references to a number of properties you must define in your view controller's class files:

- `CGFloat previousScale;`
- `CGPoint previousOffset;`
- `CGPoint previousLocation;`
- `CGPoint location;`

Ok that's it!

Unfortunately I *could not* get the scrollView to show its scrollers during the gesture.  I tried all of these strategies:

```
//Scroll indicators
self.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
self.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
[self.scrollView flashScrollIndicators];
[self.scrollView setNeedsDisplay];
```

One thing I really enjoyed is if you'll look at the last line you'll note that it grabs any final zooming that's around 100% and just rounds it to that.  You can adjust your tolerance level; I had seen this in Pages' zoom behavior and thought it would be a nice touch.

Comment: What is "aggressive subclassing?"

Answer (score 1):

I put this in the viewDidLoad method and this accomplishes the scroll view handling the two touch pan behavior and another pan gesture handler handling the one touch pan behavior -->

```
scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2

let panGR = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handlePan(_:)))
panGR.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
panGR.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1

scrollView.gestureRecognizers?.append(panGR)
```

and in the handlePan method which is a function attached to the ViewController there is simply a print statement to verify that the method is being entered -->

```
@IBAction func handlePan(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Entered handlePan numberOfTuoches: \(sender.numberOfTouches)")
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need to subclass `UIScrollView` and override its -`touchesBegan:` and `-touchesEnded:` methods to pass touches "up". This will probably also involve the subclass having a `UIView` member variable so that it knows what it's meant to pass the touches up to.

Comment: Can you clarify  what you mean Patrick?   I have subclassed UIScrollView, but I don't know how to implement the scrolling myself (move the frame of the scrollview?) and I'm not sure how to pass events to my UIView (content).   Right now, it's Responder methods are never being called.

Comment: What you would have is a UIView member variable in the UIScrollView subclass that you assign to when creating the subclass.

Then, implement -touchesBegan, -touchesMoved and -touchesEnded and have them simply pass "up" the event (by calling [uiViewMemberVariable touchesBegan:...]) unless they know it's for them.

Comment: Oh, and if you know it's for the ScrollView then just do [super touchesBegan:...] in that.

Comment: touchesmoved and friends dont work in a uiscrollview since 3.0. You might get partial operation but it is not advised

Answer (score 0):

Check out my [solution](http://kreuzundqwertz.wordpress.com/2011/12/14/uiscrollview-that-doesnt-interfere-with-content-touches/):

```
#import “JWTwoFingerScrollView.h”

@implementation JWTwoFingerScrollView

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        for (UIGestureRecognizer* r in self.gestureRecognizers) {
            NSLog(@“%@”,[r class]);
            if ([r isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
                [((UIPanGestureRecognizer*)r) setMaximumNumberOfTouches:2];
                [((UIPanGestureRecognizer*)r) setMinimumNumberOfTouches:2];
            }
        }
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)firstTouchTimerFired:(NSTimer*)timer {
    [self setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self setCanCancelContentTouches:YES];
    if ([event allTouches].count == 1){
        touchesBeganTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(firstTouchTimerFired:) userInfo: nil repeats:NO];
        [touchesBeganTimer retain];
        [touchFilter touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [touchFilter touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@“ended %i”,[event allTouches].count);
    [touchFilter touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@“canceled %i”,[event allTouches].count);
    [touchFilter touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
}

@end
```

It does not delays the first touch and does not stop when the user touches with two fingers after using one. Still it allows to cancel a just started one touch event using a timer.

Answer (score 0):

[Kenshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/382864/kenshi)'s answer in **Swift 4**

```
for gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer in self.gestureRecognizers! {
    if (gestureRecognizer is UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let panGR = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer
        panGR?.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2
    }
}
```