# UIScrollview : scroll with 2 fingers and not one

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView containing another wiew. This view need to handle single touch event for drawing. For this reason I would like to scroll using 2 fingers. 
I managed to get this working for 2.x SDK but it's no more working with 3.X series.

Do you have idea/workaround for achieving this?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787212/scrolling-with-two-fingers-with-a-uiscrollview

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I've tried exactly this as well on 3.x (never on 2.x) and never made it work correctly. It's possible that some combination of subclassing methods both approved (touchesShouldBegin...) and sketchy (touchesBegan..., hitTest...) could achieve this, but I've tried a lot of it, and could never get the event forwarding to work in a way that was consistent, and ended up with a parasitically fragile relationship to the scroll view.

I had to reimplement a scroll view from scratch to achieve this.