# Horizontal swipes in a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, swipe

I want the scroll view just scrolls vertically and I also try to capture horizontal swipes on the scroll view.

I try to subclass UIScrollView and override some method about touch event, but all failed.

The problem seems to be that when a user swipes horizontally with some accidental vertical movement(even just a little), the UIScrollView scrolls and my touchesEnded delegate method never gets called.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you are trying to capture the swipes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of overriding `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and other methods, use a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`.  It's much simpler.

[“Gesture Recognizers” in the *Event Handling Guide for iOS*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW1)
[*UISwipeGestureRecognizer Class Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But the problem still exists. The gesture selector method do NOT get called when a user swipes horizontally with some accidental vertical movement(even just a little).

Comment: What version of iOS are you targetting?

Comment: iOS 4.0. BTW, the gesture selector method gets called just when a user swipes and do NOT trigger the vertical movement.

Comment: Dig through the scroll view's gesture recognizers to find its pan gesture recognizer and do `[panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.swipeGestureRecognizer]`.  Code to find the pan gesture recognizer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3173290/77567