# How to scroll UIScrollView only with two finger swipe?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I have a `UIView` in which I draw with a finger, it all goes fine and dandy, but I need this view to be scrollable. So I made a `UIScrollView`, and embedded my drawing view in it.
But here comes the problem, I can't draw anymore since every tap goes to `UIScrollView` and it intercepts them for scrolling purposes.
What I want to do, is to make `UIScrollView` only intercept two finger swipes and with single touches and swipes just draw regularly.
How do I do that?

I draw by using simpe `touchesBegan, touchesMoved` methods by using `BezierPath`, without gesture recognizers.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787212/scrolling-with-two-fingers-with-a-uiscrollview

Comment: @Prateek not really found any working solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3173290/1492816 in [Scrolling with two fingers with a UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787212/scrolling-with-two-fingers-with-a-uiscrollview) 
People report it as working for the kind of situation you are in.

Comment: Yes, I know, sorry. Not enough rep to comment on other's posts yet.

Comment: Ok, but where do I enter such for loop? I declare my scrollView in init of some viewController, and where will my for loop go?

Comment: Each UIScrollView needs to be modified only once for this to work, might as well do it right after you create it. Or in viewDidLoad of the relevant controller, if you load from a storyboard

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this, as suggested in that answer, but to no avail. It says that method `recognizePan:` is not found. I changed it to nil, and scrolling works with two fingers only as intended, by drawing functionality is missing.
I feel like the touches are not getting to my view. What can be done?

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.scrollView action:@selector(recognizePan:)];
panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
```