# Pass certain gestures to a uiscrollview and others to its contents?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I'm sorry for being such a beginner.  I have watched a number of UIGestureRecognizer tutorials and seen some [very helpful answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787212/scrolling-with-two-fingers-with-a-uiscrollview) on SO, but making this unique combo of gestures work is evading me.  Here are the details.  Thanks in advance for the help!

FooViewController, with its own .xib in interface builder, fits into this hierarchy in iOS7:

```
UIPopover
>> PageViewController
  >> FooViewController
    >> View (built in .xib)
      >> scrollView (just a UIScrollView)
        >> DrawingView (a UIView subclass that has touch drawing capabilities)
```

It also is sometimes replaced by a subclass, we'll call it `FooViewControllerSubclass : FooViewController`.  These are the gestures I am creating:

1. When using FooViewControllerSubclass in place of FooViewController, UIPopover should receive **pinch** gestures, causing it to dismiss.  Else, it doesn't have to worry about pinches.
2. scrollView should receive **twoFingerPan** gestures, causing it to
   scroll.
3. DrawingView should receive all remaining **oneFingerGestures**, causing
   it to draw.

Currently, 1 and 3 *work great*.  But for 2, twoFingerPanning simply calls 1's pinch action.  If I comment out that pinch action, then twoFingerPanning just results in 3's oneFinger drawing actions on the DrawingView.  A summary of the code is here:

```
@implementation FooViewController

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FooViewController" owner:self options:nil];
    if (self) {
            UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGR = self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer;
            panGR.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;
}
@end


@implementation FooViewControllerSubclass

- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithWb:wb];
    if (self) {    
        UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(twoFingerPinch:)];
        [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];
    }
    return self;
}
...
- (void)twoFingerPinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

    if ([[[self nextResponder] nextResponder] isKindOfClass:([PageViewController class])]) {
        [[(PageViewController*)[[self nextResponder] nextResponder] popover] dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
}
@end


@implementation DrawingView
{
...
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
        //Does a bunch of basic drawing stuff using touchesBegan, touchesMoved, etc.  
    }
}
@end
```

As a sidenote: I'm also curious whether that whole `[[self nextResponder] nextResponder]` part is whatsoever kosher (because it works), and if not how I should be passing that info up the hierarchy.

Thanks!

Comment: Not enough info to tell what's wrong. At least, your custom scroll view is needed with creating of pan gesture recognizer.

Comment: Thanks Petro.  Actually, I don't have a custom scroll view, it's just UIScrollView.  I edited it to make that clear.  Thx,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried requiring your pan gesture recogniser to fail in order for your pinch gesture recogniser to succeed?

(In iOS 7 you can do this with `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` methods; in iOS 6 and lower, you need to subclass your pinch gesture recogniser to override `-requireGestureRecognizerToFail:`.)