# Force two finger scroll for UITableView but disable one finger scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, scroll, gestures

I want my UITableView to scroll only when using two fingers.
I realize this is not standard behavior but my app has a specific use case that users will understand. How do I do this so that two fingers scrolling works like one finger scrolling in every way while preventing one finger scrolling?

Comment: I dont think there is any straight forward method for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scrolling with two fingers with a UIScrollView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787212/scrolling-with-two-fingers-with-a-uiscrollview)

Comment: I was searching on UITableView and not UIScrollView. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.
Guto's solution did the trick.
self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mikael pointed out, this has been answered at
[Scrolling with two fingers with a UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787212/scrolling-with-two-fingers-with-a-uiscrollview)

There are many answers over the years and Guto Araujo's answer did it for me. Just changed the scrollView to my tableView instance:

`self.myTableView.panGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;`

I'll upvote Guto as soon as my rep is >= 15
Thanks Guto for the answer and Mikael for pointing in the right direction.